# Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting the below error while giving docker-compose up.

```
springbootapp    | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springbootapp    |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp    |      at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp    |      at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp    |      at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp    |      at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) [flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80) [flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:438) [flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149) [flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
springbootapp    |      at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
RUN mkdir -p /app/
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs/
ADD target/household-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
    - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
    - 5432
    ports:
    - 5434:5434
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
        - POSTGRES_USER=
        - POSTGRES_DB=test
    restart: unless-stopped
# APP*****
springbootapp:
    image: springbootapp:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: springbootapp
    expose:
    - 8080
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    links:
    - postgres
volumes:
postgres-data:
```

Comment: Hi Keerthana, please help us help you: Could you describe us what you are doing and what is triggering the error? Just droping some errormessage is probably not the best way to recieve answers. Anyhow: Welcome on board.

Comment: @MichaelA Thanks for your reply. I am trying to Dockerize a Spring boot application integrated with Postgres. Facing this issue when i am trying to up the services.

Comment: How are you configuring your application to point at the database?  Can you reformat all of the code to be in code blocks, and remove any details that aren't necessary to demonstrate the specific issue?

Comment: To connect from your spring-boot app to postgresql, you need to use the right hostname. Given your docker-compose configuration, that is `postgres`, not `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is definitely due to postgres is not running correctly or the app is not able to communicate to postgres. Use below docker-compose file and check.

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgresql:
        image: postgres:10.4
        volumes:
            - ./postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=someuser
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

You can always use following command to check if db is accepting connection.

```
psql -h [HostIP] -U [db_user] -d [db_name]
```

Comment: I am getting error psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "*.*.*.*" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: that absolutely means that the postgres you are trying to connect is not running. Did you bring the postgres container up?

Comment: The error indicates that the OP is trying to connect from his spring boot app to `localhost:5432`, which is the wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. the solution is simple.

- first open docker app,

in Terminal process;

- then you have to go to the directory where the `docker-compose.yml`
  file is located.
- then write `docker-compose up`
- next, open pgAdmin app and choose db to your spring project,
- next, enter the password and username found in `docker-compose.yml`
  (username:  *image*,  password: *POSTGRES_PASSWORD*),
- finally run the spring boot project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your ports.
You are exposing port
-5432
but you are mapping ports

- 5434:5434
  They have to be both the same.

Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).